# Manual/non-JS reCAPTCHA not translating

Tags: localization, recaptcha

When JavaScript is disabled reCAPTCHA uses a JS-independent captcha (*obviously*). But the problem is that the text/links are not translated.

In fact, for the manual challenge the following text is additionally displayed:

> "We need to make sure you are a human. Please solve the challenge below, and click the I'm a Human button to get a confirmation code. To make this process easier in the future, we recommend you enable Javascript."

The text above is in English even though I've set "lang: 'es'" (but obviously this doesn't work because it's set in JavaScript).

Is there a certain way to **specify the language** for the manual challenge? (different to the JS "lang: 'es'" JS settting)
Or **can custom translations be written** for the manual challenge?

Answer (score 0):

You can only add `hl=es` parameter to link for noscript